# Flutter FirebaseAuth token issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

[FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API securetoken.googleapis.com method google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken are blocked. ].

I receive this error when try to create or update or delete document in CloudFirestore. However, I receive this after about 1 hour. OAuth in Goolge Cloud Console enabled, Token Services API enabled too.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple possibilities and causes for this error. I am listing some of them for you to look, analyse and try upon.

**Solution 1 :**

To configure that API restrictions, please go to the Credentials page [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials] and then follow the instructions below:

1. Click the API key to configure
2. Select Restrict key in the API restrictions section.
3. Select all API names that your API key needs to call from the dropdown - “Identity Toolkit API”,  “Token Service API”
4. Save the changes.

You may also refer to these documentations[1][2] regarding managing API keys for Firebase.

[1]https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys 
[2]https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

**Solution 2 :**

Set the requirements of auth in the Firestore rules properly.  See Get started with Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

This is how you can set firestore rules if auth is required :

```
rules_version = '2'; 
service cloud.firestore { 
match /databases/{database}/documents { 
match /{document=**} {
 allow read, write:
 if request.auth != null;
 } } }
```

**Solution 3 :**

If you are using the method getIdToken to call and retrieve the Firebase token ID, you need to do the following :

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
String token;
user.getIdToken().then((result) {
token = result.token;
});
```

You can't call `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().getIdToken()` as it will not work.